# Sorting å,ä,ö characters in MS Search Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, search-engine

Search Server treats å,ä,ö characters as a,a,o when i order by title i.e. Is there some way to make the search result to order them correctly?

Best regards, 
Mattias

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are looking for is called *collation*. Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260.aspx).

Comment: Search Server requires Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS to be used. I dont know if you could use collation in the specific SQL-query when performing a search. I dont have the possibility to try it out atm. Anyone know if its applicable?

Comment: You can define the collation on a query, using a query operator `COLLATE` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx

Comment: I tried but COLLATE doesnt seem to be supported in the web service query in Search Server. In regular queries outside Search Server its doable, but not in this case due to some restrictions apparently. Ive reported it to microsoft